# Google places API returning different results

Tags: google-api

I have written a python program which use google places API to extract list of restaurants from a given coordinates. Google API is returning different results when i am running the same code multiple times. for e.g sometime it returns 5 restaurants and sometimes it returns 12 restaurants by running the same program.

Below is the syntax to locate the relevant coordinates for fetching the data:

'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+coordinate+'&keyword='+str(keyword)+'&key='+str(api_key)+'&rankby=distance'

where coordinate is passed from the program and keyword is "restaurant".

Anyone knows what could be a issue here?